# How to add a Rake task to the default Rake task?

Tags: ruby, rake

Somehow Rspec and Cucumber are making it into my default rake task (which is fine because I want them there). But I have tried adding additional tasks to the default task and it has no effect.

What is the proper way to add tasks to the default rake task?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Typically your Rakefile will have something like this:

```
task :default => [:spec]
```

You just need to add more tasks into this list.

Answer (score 8):

The answer from [davogenes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59631/davogones) is correct for non-namespaced rake tasks.

If you want to have a default task in namespaces you need to do the following

```
namespace :mynamespace do
  desc "This should be the default"
  task :mydefault do
    Do.something_by_default
  end

  desc "Another task in this namespace"
  task :other do
    Do.something
  end
end

desc "This is the default task of mynamespace"
task mynamespace: 'mynamespace:mydefault'
```

Then you can run `rake mynamespace` as well as `rake mynamespace:other` or `rake mynamespace:mydefault`.

Comment: You can also remove the "desc" line from the namespaced default task so it won't show up in `rake --tasks` (only the mynamespace and the mynamespace:other will show up in the --tasks command then). If you don't do this, both will be present in the --tasks command, thus looking duplicated.